# My query don't return null values of the second table

Tags: sql

[result of the query exposed below with my query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGZkI.png)

In the previous image we can see the model of the two tables(the description field is missing in the second table of the model but is actually in the database).
My goal is the following:

```
id_valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta  descripcion   descripcion
            1                    Alarma        alarma
            2                    Composicion   composicion
            3                    Foto          foto
            4                    Valor pru1    null
            5                    Valor pru2    null
            6                    Valor check   null
```

The values on the table are the following

The table valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta:
[The table valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bna6U.png)

the table valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta_idioma:

[the table valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta_idioma:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycPB3.png)

my query:

```
select vtae.id_valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta,vtae.descripcion, vtaei.descripcion from 
maestros.valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta vtae
LEFT JOIN   maestros.valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta_idioma vtaei  on 
vtae.id_valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta=vtaei.id_valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta
where vtaei.id_idioma = 3;
```

Comment: Move the vtaei.id_idioma condition from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product (DBVisualizer is a SQL client tool that can connect to many different DBMS and is irrelevant for a SQL problem) Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the condition on the *second* table in a `LEFT JOIN` to the `ON` clause:

```
select vtae.id_valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta,vtae.descripcion, vtaei.descripcion
from maestros.valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta vtae left join
     maestros.valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta_idioma vtaei
     on vtae.id_valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta = vtaei.id_valor_tipo_atributo_etiqueta and
        vtaei.id_idioma = 3;
```